# Where does environment.production come from?

Tags: angular-cli

I'm using Angular CLI. It generated the following `index.html` for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AuthorWizard</title>
  <base href="/">

  {{#unless environment.production}}
  <script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  {{/unless}}
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </div>

    {{#each scripts.polyfills}}
    <script src="{{.}}"></script>
    {{/each}}
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

I'm curious about the following three lines:

```
  {{#unless environment.production}}
  <script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  {{/unless}}
```

If I remove those lines, live reload stops working. However, if I keep the lines in, I get an error when I run my tests. I want to configure that script tag to only show up when, say, `environment.development` is *true* as opposed to when `environment.production` is false.

Where does `environment.production` come from?

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax for Handlebars which CLI uses internally for parsing the document. So leave it as it is. use the built up code from `/dist` to serve the project.

In development version of CLI, handlebars is removed and webpack is used instead, where this code is removed.